# R correcting inconsistent data records

Tags: r, plot, outliers

I am recording four variables every 5 minutes. When I plot a time series in R of the four variables I realize variable 3 is recording inconsistent data due to a mistake in the data collection (recording device error/sensor error). How can I correct the data recordings?

The data records of variable 3 show some abnormal jumps, and it's not a phisical effect of the studied variable. The image shows one week of data recordings with daily oscillations. There should not be such high jumps between two readings in a row.
I tried some R outliers package some time ago, but got not result with it...

[image]

When I plot the entire time series the result is worse.

[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks

I share the data from image 1:

[Figure 1 csv data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wEDWhXZ5RqI-6Z1qYtRDQtCk5kBZx9JS)

Comment: It seems like the jumps are fairly large. You can write a script that loops through and removes data points that jump >50 units in a single interval. Can you provide a working example so we can test out possible solutions.

Comment: A cheap-and-easy (meaning: somewhat robust but not without consequences) method would be to compare each value with a moving `median`. Median filters ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_filter)) can be good but result in lagged data. However, checking for a nominal distance from this lagged moving median would help filter out the problem points. (That is, use the moving-median to find the outliers, not to smooth the data.)

Comment: If you share some data, it would be easier to help. Can you add to your question the output from `dput(head(x,n=20))` with at least 2-3 known bad-spikes?

Comment: @r2evans. I shared the data from Figure1 as a csv file. I did not share it as dput because there would be a lot of readings if I want to show 2-3 bad-splikes (readings are every 5 minutes).

Comment: I thought also to write some script in R, as @JusGettinStarted commented, but don't know how to do it in R. Anyway thanks for the ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading in your data and plotting, I see this:

```r
df <- read.csv("~/StackOverflow/RaülOo.csv")
df$TIMESTAMP <- as.POSIXct(df$TIMESTAMP)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
gather(df, k, v, -X, -TIMESTAMP) %>%
  ggplot(aes(TIMESTAMP, v, color=k)) +
  geom_path()
```

[image: unfiltered]

Is it as simple as "anything above -50"? The deciles look like this:

```r
quantile(unlist(df[,3:6]), seq(0,1,len=11))
#        0%       10%       20%       30%       40%       50%       60%       70% 
# -122.7000  -22.9600  -17.5500  -13.4200  -10.0700   -5.9615    3.4800   16.0500 
#       80%       90%      100% 
#   26.6040   35.6860   81.4000
```

The IQR is around 37. Similar to "whiskers" in boxplots, it might be realistic to assume ["1.5 IQR"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_plot), that is: values below "1.5 times IQR  below the lower quartile" (and likewise above, though not present in this data) might safely be considered outliers.

```r
(q <- quantile(unlist(df[,3:6]), c(0.25, 0.75)))
#      25%      75% 
# -15.4000  22.0025 
unname( q[1] - 1.5*diff(q) ) # "unname" only to remove the now-misleading percentile label
# -71.50375 
gather(df, k, v, -X, -TIMESTAMP) %>%
  filter(v > q[1] - 1.5*diff(q)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(TIMESTAMP, v, color=k)) +
  geom_path()
```

[image: partially filtered]

so perhaps 1.5 is not-strong-enough to really identify outliers, but it depends on your needs. If all you need is a cleaned-up plot (and some outliers are not debilitating), then I suggest using the standard "1.5 times IQR" suffices. If you want to be more controlling about it, perhaps using something closer to 1 will work.

```r
gather(df, k, v, -X, -TIMESTAMP) %>%
  filter(v > q[1] - diff(q)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(TIMESTAMP, v, color=k)) +
  geom_path()
```

[image: filtered]

If you need this back in "wide" format, you can do:

```r
gather(df, k, v, -X, -TIMESTAMP) %>%
  filter(v > -50) %>%
  spread(k, v) %>%
  slice(37:43) # just for demonstration
#    X           TIMESTAMP   four    one  three    two
# 1 37 2018-07-15 03:05:00 -21.68 -32.04 -23.11 -12.87
# 2 38 2018-07-15 03:10:00 -21.79 -31.71 -23.11 -12.87
# 3 39 2018-07-15 03:15:00 -21.79 -31.71 -23.11 -12.87
# 4 40 2018-07-15 03:20:00 -21.79 -31.71 -23.11 -12.87
# 5 41 2018-07-15 03:25:00 -17.43 -25.37     NA -10.29
# 6 42 2018-07-15 03:30:00 -21.79 -31.71 -23.11 -12.87
# 7 43 2018-07-15 03:35:00 -21.79 -31.28 -23.11 -12.87
```

where your outliers are now `NA`. A more-succinct, non-`dplyr`/`tidyr` alternative could be:

```r
df[,3:6] <- lapply(df[,3:6], function(a) ifelse(a < -50, NA, a))
```

and then whatever follow-on processing or plotting you do would need to take into account (ignore) `NA` values.

---

I'll go one step further, since it might be interesting (to you) to know how frequently (or periodically) the bad-data is coming in.

```r
newdat <- df %>%
  gather(k, v, -X, -TIMESTAMP) %>%
  mutate(v = if_else(v < q[1] - diff(q), NA_real_, v))
baddat <- filter(newdat, is.na(v))
newdat <- filter(newdat, !is.na(v))
baddat$v <- min(newdat$v) - 5 # arbitrary

ggplot(newdat, aes(TIMESTAMP, v, color = k)) +
  geom_path() +
  geom_point(data = baddat)
```

[image: filtered with outlier dots]

Here you can see where the problem data points are located without scaling-out the rest of the chart.

---

Notes

- This seems like a quick hack to get you started. For example, if instead of homogeneous your four different measurements are on vastly different scales, this would need to be done per-column.
- I used `dplyr` for data-mangling, though they are not strictly required. This could easily have been done in base-R with relatively simple functions. The use of `ggplot2` mandated long-data, ergo `tidyr::gather` (and `tidyr::spread`); if you are using base graphics, then you might not need to reshape the data (which suggests per-column data-replacement might be preferred).

Comment: Thanks for the solution, this really helps me. I will try with the whole data set and see how it works, I guess I will have to play with the x * IQR and the lower quartile. The last step where you detect the cleaned data is also really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an a possible solution, but first we need to generate some data that represents your problem. What is nice about your scenario is that the spurious data points are large spikes that fairly obvious even visually.

### Generate Data

```
set.seed(15161)
x <- seq(pi/10,10*pi,by=pi/100)
y <- sin(x) # using sin() generates some osciliating data
z <- sample(c(0,-5),length(y),
            prob=c(0.99,0.01),replace=TRUE) # pepper the data with random spikes
y <- y + z
df <- data.frame(cbind(x,y,z))
length(which(df$z==-5)) # the number of spikes ~ 13
plot(df$x,df$y,type="l",ylim=c(-10,2),col="blue",xlab="x",ylab="y")
abline(h=0,lty=5)
```

[image]

### Removing Spurious Measurements (cleaning the data)

In the data you present, the spurious data points are very large compared to the background of good measurements. That is your measurements are moving along nicely in a slowly increasing or decreasing manner, then blam the jump/drop by > 20 units. So i wrote a function that will spot and remove any data points that represent an increase/decrease above some threshold (in your case ~ 20 units, in my working example above ~2 units should suffice).

Function code is :

```
f <- function(df,clean,threshold){
  y <- df[,clean]
  for(i in 1:length(y)){
    if(is.na(y[i]) | is.na(y[i+1])){
      next
    }
    if(abs(y[i+1]-y[i])>threshold){
      y[i+1] <- NA
    }
  }
  return(df[!is.na(y),])
}
cleaned.df <- f(df,clean="y",threshold=2) # Run the function to clean the data
length(which(cleaned.df$z==-5)) # number of spikes in cleaned data is now 0
```

Plot the cleaned results

```
plot(cleaned.df$x,cleaned.df$y,type="l",ylim=c(-10,2),col="blue",xlab="x",ylab="y")
abline(h=0,lty=5)
```

[image]

### Notes and Caveats

1. Make sure your data is **sequentially ordered** before running the function (i.e chronologically sorted measurements)
2. I recommend you choose a threshold around 20 units (just by visual inspection of your graph this seems adequate.
3. The cleaning function may not be effective at removing 2 or more consecutive spikes. **However** you can run the data through the cleaning function multiple times and that should work.
4. There are more rigorous approaches we can devise but i thought this solution would be simple and effective. Let us know if you still have issues and we can develop more rigorous solutions.

### Edit 1 :

I just saw that you uploaded some actual data. Tweaked the function slightly to accommodate spikes that change the sign of measurements. Here are the results as applies to your data, which looks like it works to me.

```
df <- read.csv("figure1data.csv")
plot(df$X,df$three,type="l",col="blue",xlab="x",ylab="y",ylim=c(-150,50))
    abline(h=0,lty=5)
```

[image]

```
cleaned.df1 <- f(df,clean="three",threshold=20)
plot(cleaned.df1$X,cleaned.df1$three,type="l",col="blue",xlab="x",ylab="y",
     ylim=c(-150,50))
abline(h=0,lty=5)
```

[image]

### Edit 2 : Response to OP comments

To remove cases where consecutive spikes occur simply re-run the function on the cleaned data.

```
cleaned.df2 <- f(cleaned.df1,clean="three",threshold=20)
```

To restore all rows to the data and convert spiked variable "three" points as `NA` simply merge the data back as follows.

```
New.df <- merge(df[,colnames(df)!="three"],
               cleaned.df2[,colnames(df) %in% c("X","three")],
               by="X",all.x=TRUE)
```

To check that things are working as expected

```
df[which(!complete.cases(New.df)),] 
New.df[which(!complete.cases(New.df)),]
```

you see clearly that rows with variable "three" spikes are now in `NA` in the `New.df`

Comment: This solution works quite well! I managed to remove near all the spikes of the whole data frame. As you said there are some consecutive spikes that couldn't be removed, but very few (I can always remove them by hand, better than removing hundreds).
The only problem I found is that the code removes all the row data from all the variables when the cleaned variable has NA as value.

Comment: to remove consecuetive spikes no need to do it by hand, just re-run the function again on the cleaned data. The second run should remove any remaining spikes.

Comment: i will update the function so it does not remove rows with NAs

Comment: Many thanks! It worked really nice, I could correct the whole dataset for further analysis after re-running the function and erasing all the spikes. I only had a little problem with a whole dataset when I have for example 100 rows with a correct TIMESTAMP but NA values on variable 3: If the difference between the value before and after the NA rows was greater than my threshold the next value after the NA rows is erased. But not a great problem since my sampling rate is 5 minutes and not great changes happen.